# jquery animate scoll not working in iframe?

Tags: jquery, facebook, iframe, jquery-animate

This is working:

```
$('html, body').animate({scrollTop:0});
```

But its not if I use it inside Facebook-Tab!
If this is too less information to answer the question I come up with some more details for you.

May it be becouse of the iframe? I tried it with another selector inside my Facebook-Tab (the container div) but its not working too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that the IFrame (Javascript: window) is exactly the size of the document. So there is nothing to scroll. When you want to scroll, you have to use the FB.Canvas.* methods:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Canvas.scrollTo/

Answer (score 0):

try `$('body').animate({scrollTop:0});`  Or inserting a DIV into your DOM and using `$('#some_div_id').animate({scrollTop:0});`

Or try this code in place of yours for testing purposes, once you get the below code working, then slowly add in your own content until it breaks.  I've validated that scrollTop:0 will work just fine on a page tab.

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
  function gotoTop() {
    $('body').animate({scrollTop:0});
  }
</script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="top-div" style="width:300px; height: 800px; padding: 30px 10px; background-color: #eeaaaa;">
    This is top-div
  </div>

  <div id="bottom-div" style="width:300px; height: 100px; padding: 30px 10px; background-color: #aaeeaa;">
    This is bottom div
    <a href="javascript:gotoTop()">goto top</a>
  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: as i said... no result with an extra div to scroll :( ... also body alone isnt doing anything

Comment: It's hard trying to swat bugs I cannot see.  Can you at least give a hint of the code you're using?    Or try my above code and see if it works for you.